# BadMethodCallException: Method waitForTextPresent not defined

Tags: php, selenium, tdd, yii, phpunit

I'm running server on Mandriva 2011
Apache 2.2.22
PHP 5.3.14
PHPUnit Version 3.3.17
Selenium Server 2.24.2
Yii 1.1.10
I pulled some work to my home and see, that I can`t run standard tests..

```
PHPUnit 3.3.17 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.EE

Time: 33 seconds

There were 2 errors:

1) testContact(SiteTest)
BadMethodCallException: Method waitForTextPresent not defined.
/home/user/server/hosts/cmf/www/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php:63
/home/user/server/hosts/cmf/www/protected/tests/functional/SiteTest.php:21
/home/user/server/hosts/cmf/www/protected/tests/functional/SiteTest.php:21

2) testLoginLogout(SiteTest)
BadMethodCallException: Method waitForTextPresent not defined.
/home/user/server/hosts/cmf/www/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php:63
/home/user/server/hosts/cmf/www/protected/tests/functional/SiteTest.php:36
/home/user/server/hosts/cmf/www/protected/tests/functional/SiteTest.php:36

FAILURES!                                                                                                                                   
Tests: 3, Assertions: 4, Errors: 2.
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've  just upgraded PHPUnit to v.3.6.11 from pear. And problem solved.
It's strange that it`s not lastversioned from mandriva repo.